# Javascript/Jquery using mysql for initial config

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm using codeigniter and I have a timeout function using jquery. I just need to find a way to get a number (an int) from a field in the database the application is using and set the initial int in the javascript file to it. As you can see in the code '*900000*' needs to be dynamically received from a database table. Since it does not need ajax(does not need dynamically receive data in real time) I would like to find a lighter solution if possible. What would be the best practice in this situation?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    idleTimer = null;
    logoutTimer = null;
    idleWait = 900000; //15 minutes
    logoutWait = 30000; //30 sec
    timeUp = false;
```

Comment: Just output the value from PHP: `idlewait = <?php echo $idlewait; ?>;`

Comment: I am not familiar with codeigniter, but you can include php directly in your javascript. `idleWait = <?=$php_variable;?>;` for example.

Comment: Yea, the only thing is I have to get it from the database. If having a short php function that connects to the database and gets the timeout in the javscript page itself is the best way to do it, then I guess I can do it that way. Just wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @ALF JavaScript cannot talk directly to the database.  It has to be done by PHP, so it is typically handled this way.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `echo` to output the value at that point in the script.

```
idleWait = <? echo $timeoutValueRetrievedFromDataBase ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not run in your standard JS file without quite a bit of modification. First off, find the .php file where your `<head>` section is located. Find the first `<script>` tag, you will want to work before this. That way you can go ahead and set a variable that will be ready when your JS file gets loaded.

Right above your first `<script>` tag insert something like this

```
<script>
<?php
    //you will need to connect to db here and get your timeout value from the database
    //we assume $timeout has the correct value in it
    echo "var phpTimeout = $timeout;"
?>
</script>
```

You would then go into the script you pasted into the question and do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    idleTimer = null;
    logoutTimer = null;
    idleWait = phpTimeout; //this is the variable we set earlier in the <head> of the document
    logoutWait = 30000; //30 sec
    timeUp = false;
```